# An .adp proj openning wih parameter

Tags: parameters, ms-access-2010

I have an .adp project, I want to open it different at the different workstations.
Is it possible to sent parameter with the shortcut? or another way.
How do i get the parameter, which I sent, with the appllication adp?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `/cmd` [Command-Line Switch](https://www.devhut.net/microsoft-access-command-line-switches/)?

Comment: I'm guessing you're aware Microsoft deprecated ADP (Access Data Project) database format over 10 years ago.  I'm just leaving this note for other readers who may not be aware.